# How to integrate over infinitesimal conformal transformation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conformal-field-theory

Polchinski Vol. 1 (Sec. 2.4): I'm trying to derive

$$(∂w)^2T(w)=T(z)−\frac{c}{12}\{w,z\}\tag{2.4.26}$$

from its infinitesimal version given by

$$δT (w) = −\epsilon(w) ∂T (w) − 2 \epsilon ′ (w) T (w) − \frac{c}{12}\epsilon′′′(w). \tag{2.4.24}$$
How do you do that?

Can anyone, please, also tell me how does one integrate over an infinitesimal variation in general?

Comment: See e.g. Blumenhagen et. al. p. 72-73.